# Invoke-Command script block not generating output

Tags: shell, powershell, citrix

I am trying to use a script block in a remote powershell session. This command is working and I get an output about the machine state:

```
$SecurePassword = $ParamPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword
$ParamDomain = 'mydomain'
$ParamHostname = "myhostname"

$fullhost =  "$ParamDomain"+"\"+"$ParamHostname"  

#Get-BrokerMachine No1
if ($ParamCommand -eq 'Get-BrokerMachine'){
$s = New-PSSession -computerName $desktopbroker -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { param( $fullhost ) ;asnp citrix.* ; Get-BrokerMachine -machinename $fullhost  } -Args $fullhost
}
```

My second iteration of this, also using a scriptblock, is failing. The command `Get-BrokerMachine` is not executed and there is no output.

```
#Get-BrokerMachine No2
if ($ParamCommand -eq 'Get-BrokerMachine'){
$ScriptBlock = {
    asnp citrix.* ; Get-BrokerMachine -machinename $fullhost 
};
$s = New-PSSession -computerName $desktopbroker -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock 

}
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with the second script?

Comment: `$fullhost` is most likely $null as it is not passed to the command. You need to pass `$fullhost` as an argument I would bet. You are doing that in your first example. Not your second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one important thing that is missing in your second script is that you are not passing `$fullhost` as an argument. When the scriptblock gets called on the remote system `$fullhost` would be `$null`.

Rough guess would be you need to do something like this:

```
#Get-BrokerMachine No2
if ($ParamCommand -eq 'Get-BrokerMachine'){
    $ScriptBlock = {
        param($host)
        asnp citrix.* ; Get-BrokerMachine -machinename $host 
    };
    $s = New-PSSession -computerName $desktopbroker -credential $cred
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $fullhost
}
```

I changed the name of the variable inside the scriptblock to `$host` to remove the potential perceived ambiguity of the scopes.