# Changing IP with PowerCLI in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli

I've created a script that makes a clone of a VM in vCenter, renames it, then changes the IP of the VM once it has powered up (from the IP of the template). I do this by having a prompt ask what the IP should be. The only issue, is that I need to enter the required IP twice. Once to label the VM, and then again to change the ip of the box.

Is there a way of carrying over the variable '$NewVMIP' that is entered here:

```
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Connect-VIServer -Server vcenter01 -User myusername -Password Password1

Start-Sleep -s 6
$TemplateVM = "Windows QA - 172.30.30.110 - TEMPLATE"
$NewVMIP = Read-Host "Please input IP of new VM"
$NewVMFor = Read-Host "Please input Who This VM is For?"
$NewVMDate = Read-Host "Please input todays date"

$NewVMName = "Windows QA - $NewVMIP - $NewVMFor - $NewVMDate"

New-VM -Name $NewVMName -VM $TemplateVM -VMHost "esx01.coname.local"

Move-VM -VM $NewVMName -Destination Testing

Start-VM -VM $NewVMName

Start-Sleep -s 200
```

To the second part of the script:

```
$username = "vmadmin"
$password = "Password1"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr


Invoke-Command -ComputerName 172.30.30.110 -ScriptBlock {

$NewVMIP = Read-Host "Enter IP"
$subnet = "255.255.255.0"
$gateway = "172.30.30.1"

netsh int ip set address "Local Area Connection" static "$NewVMIP" "255.255.255.0" "172.30.30.1"

} -credential $cred
```

So I don't have to enter the IP a second time?

I assume this has something to do with the second part of the script being run on the VM/vCenter rather than the remote location, therefore the variable doesn't get passed along. I have tried to specify a global variable such as $Global:NewVMIP but this didn't work

Thank you in advance for your help.

Marc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke-Command script block not generating output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370042/invoke-command-script-block-not-generating-output) Look at my answer. `$NewVMIP` is null when the command is called.

Answer (score 1):

The one important thing that is missing in your second script is that you are not passing `$NewVMIP` as an argument. When the scriptblock gets called on the remote system `$NewVMIP` would be `$null`.

Rough guess would be you need to do something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 172.30.30.110 -ScriptBlock {
    param($ip)

    $NewVMIP = Read-Host "Enter IP"
    $subnet = "255.255.255.0"
    $gateway = "172.30.30.1"

    netsh int ip set address "Local Area Connection" static "$ip" "255.255.255.0" "172.30.30.1"

} -credential $cred -ArgumentList $NewVMIP
```

Answer (score 0):

[Set-VMGuestNetworkInterface](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41/html/Set-VMGuestNetworkInterface.html) could be another way to skin the cat?

Or better yet, change the IP address with sysprep via [Set-OSCustomizationNicMapping](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Set-OSCustomizationNicMapping.html).